# Mongo map.reduce error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

```js
var mapFunction1 = function() {

    for (var idx = 0; idx < this.account.length; idx++) {
        emit("saldo", this.account[idx].balance);
    }

};

var reduceFunction1 = function(keyBalance, valuesBalance) {
    return Array.sum(valuesBalance);
};

db.people.mapReduce(mapFunction1, reduceFunction1, {
    out : "saldo"
})

db.saldo.find()
```

And show error

> > uncaught exception: map reduce failed:{
> >         "errmsg" : "exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined\n    at _funcs1 (_funcs1:2:37) near 'is.account.length; i++) '  (line 2)",
> >         "code" : 16722,
> >         "ok" : 0

Comment: Seems the downvotes here are unfair for someone just seeking knowledege

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that "length" is **not defined** on an object that is found in your document and most likely because the property does not exist.

Since this is JavaScript evaluation within a [`mapReduce`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) process then your JavaScript tests need to be "strict" to testing these conditions:

```js
var mapFunction1 = function() {
   if ( this.hasOwnProperty("account") {
       for (var idx = 0; idx < this.account.length; idx++) {
           emit("saldo", this.account[idx].balance);
       }
   }
}
```

So [**`.hasOwnProperty()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) here is the key to avoiding such errors by testing that this actually *exists* in the object.